# Trap output of a function, but let it exit

Tags: bash

Suppose we have `fct` defined like so:

```
fct() {
  echo words
  read -n1 x
  [ $x == q ] && exit
}
```

Calling `fct` works as expected, but if you need to trap its output, `` var=`fct` ``, `exit` does not work. According to what I found searching on the net, `exit` works, but it exit a spawned shell. It does work with `kill -s KILL $$`, so `fct` runs in the same process as `=`, just not the same context and `exit` quit only the context, not the shell.

Is there a way we can call `fct` to trap its output and let `exit` quit the same context as the equal? Or is there any other way than hard killing to stop the process?

Comment: The standard way to achieve something similar without making a mess: add a `trap` for `SIGINT`, and set a flag in the handler.  Then check for said flag at convenient points in your script.  You'll then be able to interupt your script with `Ctrl-C`.

Comment: "so fct runs in the same process as =, just not the same context " <- this is false. It runs in a separate process, the `$$` variable is just not updated. This is the exact reason why `$BASHPID` exists (see documentation).

Comment: Thanks @Patrick, you are right, it does not seem to be running in the same process id, I checked it with ps while it was sleeping (I added a sleep) and it spawn a subprocess. I looked at documentation and it does show a different $BASHPID if run in subshell (surrounded with single parentheses commands), but not surrounded with $(...) commands or backticks. So we cannot access it's output and let it exit.

Comment: @SatoKatsura, what I'm doing, is a script that is sourced initially to set the prompt and the environnement. The script need input from the user  (choose an alternate environnement/project), but I want `^D` to work. So that the user can quit the terminal if he realize he opened it accidentally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I figured it out!**

We can pass the stream through a temporary file! In linux, we can pass it through a file in `/dev/shm`, so that the data stays in memory. We can also wrap it in a funcion:

```
get_output() {
  $1 > /dev/shm/bash_pipe
  eval $2=`cat /dev/shm/bash_pipe`
  rm /dev/shm/bash_pipe
}
```

We can then use it like so: `get_output fct var` and you can use the output of `fct` with `$var`.